# Простенькое приложение крашится

Tags: android

Решил сделать небольшое приложение с `ListView`. Но приложение отказалось запускаться.

Строчка в которой вылетает прога: `lsview.setAdapter(listadapter);`

То есть где-то проблема с адаптером. Но я уже все пересмотрел, перелопатил дебагером и сверил с уроком по которому учил все это дело. Студия ошибок не выдает. Лог пустой, просто показывает, что крашится прога.

Если убрать `SimpleAdapter` и привязать к `ListView` другой адаптер типа `ArrayAddapter`, то все пашет.

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    public int [] val=new int[]{41,24,78,12,56,92};
    public ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> listval;
    public Map<String,Object> maplist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listval=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(val.length);
        for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
            maplist=new HashMap<String,Object>();
            maplist.put("ll",val[i]);
            maplist.put("pb",val[i]);
            maplist.put("Text", "Day " + i + ": " + val[i] + "%");
            listval.add(maplist);
        }
        String from[]=new String[]{"ll","pb","Text"};
        int[] to=new int[]{R.id.llLoad,R.id.pbLoad,R.id.tvLoad};
        SimpleAdapter listadapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listval,R.layout.listview,from,to);
        //listadapter.setViewBinder(new MySimpleViewBinder());
        ListView lsview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
       lsview.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть стек трейс и описание ошибки показали. А то так можно долго гадать по кофейной гуще. И код лайата R.layout.listview тоже не помешает.

Answer (score 1):

у вас в строке

```
SimpleAdapter listadapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, listval, R.layout.listview, from, to);
```

должно быть

```
R.layout.item
```

вместо

```
R.layout.listview
```

результат

```
SimpleAdapter listadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listval, R.layout.item, from, to);
```

Comment: listview.xml - это файл элементов списка. Все верно. Так что нет, не в этом дело.

Comment: @MediaPortal бывает. Тут фишка была в том, что item нужно было включат в list. Главное нашли проблему ))

Comment: Я даже изменил layout.xml на item.xml. Но ошибка явно не в этом.

Comment: Ничего я не нашел.

Comment: @MediaPortal если еще не работает, покажите log ошибки который при запуске дает. Оттуда можно узнать только

Comment: так нету ошибок в логе. Нигде. Это паранормальный баг. Просто какой то баг Шрёдингера. Фишка в том что программа крашится вовсе после метода OnCreate. Но причина краша метод setAdapter. Я уже думал может эмулятор чудит или студия. Но нет, без setAdapter все запускает.

Comment: а вы пробовали перезапустить сам AndroidStudio? может давно работает

Comment: а студия такое чудить может? Вылатает в каком-то методе в классе Looper.java. Там какой-то бесконечный цикл. Ща попробую студию перезапустить.

Comment: @MediaPortal не может в логе не быть ошибки, если приложение падает, то либо из за ошибки ява кода и тогда будет полноценный стек трейс в логе, либо где то в нативном коде и тогда будет малоинформативный код ошибки, но что то будет в любом случае.

Comment: Нету. 18:11:47 Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)
18:12:31 Gradle sync started
18:14:28 Gradle sync completed
18:14:31 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
18:14:44 Gradle build finished in 14s 641ms
18:21:51 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
18:21:56 Gradle build finished in 5s 179ms
18:23:42 Session 'app': Launched on Nexus_4_API_19 [emulator-5554]

Comment: А причем тут лог андройд студии? Ошибки выполнения в логе устройства отображаются, посмотреть его можно в Android Monitor (Alt+6) на закладке logcat.